# Javascript adding decimals to a number

Tags: javascript

Why does this occur:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var bob=new Number(1);  
    for (var i=0; i<8 ;i++){        
        bob=Number(bob+1.1)             
    }

}
```

Alerts:
2.1

3.2

4.300000000000001

5.4

6.5

7.6

8.7

9.799999999999999

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem for workarounds and discussion of this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rounding issues. `4.3` has no exact representation in binary.

How exactly numbers get stored in JavaScript is actually implementation-specific, but it is always a binary floating point.

**Edit:**

Looks like my information is a little outdated. The standard now specifies *doubleprecision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values*

Links:

- [offical PDF](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)
- [HTML version](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5)

Comment: There are fixed formats that would be able to store 4.3 exactly. The problem is that javascript uses floats.

Answer (score 0):

Because in Javascript, "numbers" default to floating point.  Even "i" ;-)  And, of course, "Bob".

And floating point numbers are *approximations*.

If you want, you can use "floor()" and "ceil()"

PS:
You can also use parseInt() to convert a float to an int:

```
parseInt (4.33) // Result = 4
```

Or round():

```
round (3.2 + 1.1) // 4.3, not 4.300000000000001
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the javascript Number is actually a double precision float:

From the spec:

```
4.3.19
 Number value
  primitive value corresponding to a double-precision
  64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with how the computer, which works on base(2), calculates base(10) arithmetic. There's a lot of articles explaining the nuances.

If you haven't solved your problem yet, whenever you use floating point numbers, you should also massage the output with the appropriate function.

I typically use [`number.toFixed()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) which will round to an appropriate number of decimal places.

Comment: The problem is that the designers of JavaScript decided to use a format that works that way, and not provide a number type that handles base 10 correctly by default.